# Error (404) Importing a PBIX file into a PowerBI Group

Tags: powerbi

I’m getting a 404 response when importing a PBIX file into a PowerBI group, here’s the url:

https://api.powerbi.com/beta/myorg/groups/460825fc-beeb-4f4b-8580-4c0700753266/imports?datasetDisplayName=MyMovies_Imported&nameConflict=Ignore

Same request but without the group works ok:

https://api.powerbi.com/beta/myorg/imports?datasetDisplayName=MyMovies_Imported&nameConflict=Ignore

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Importing into a group is not currently supported. We are looking at add this soon.